# Counting the number of lines in a gzip file using python

Tags: python, gzip

I'm trying to count the number of lines in a gz archive. There is only 1 json format text file per gz. But when I open the archive and count the lines the count is way off what I'd expect. The file contains 522 lines, but my code is returning 668480 lines.

```
import gzip
f = gzip.open(myfile, 'rb')
file_content = f.read()
for i, l in enumerate(file_content):
    pass
i += 1
print("File {1} contain {0} lines".format(i, myfile))
```

Comment: Paste the sample Json file.

Comment: Do you need to open in `rb` for gzip?

Comment: Maybe your code counts base on how many \n it sees, and you counts base on when a json ends ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are iterating over all characters not the lines. You can iterate lines the following way

```
import gzip
with gzip.open(myfile, 'rb') as f:
    for i, l in enumerate(f):
        pass
print("File {1} contain {0} lines".format(i + 1, myfile))
```

Comment: This is so far the best solution I have found. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: print(f"File {myfile} contain {i+1} lines")

Answer (score 1):

For a performant way to count the lines in a gzip file you can use the `pragzip` package:

```py
import pragzip

result = 0
with pragzip.open(myfile) as file:
    while chunk := file.read( 1024*1024 ):
        result += chunk.count(b'\n')
print(f"Number of lines: {result}")
```

Comparing the timing of the above with @DmitryKovriga's answer:

```
Number of lines: 33468793
Elapsed time is 22.373915 seconds.

File datasets/binance-futures_incremental_book_L2_2020-07-01_BTCUSDT.csv.gz contain 33468793 lines
Elapsed time is 31.278056 seconds.
```

A speed up of more like 10x should be possible with a suitable setup. See  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/713093/163459 for more info.